# Rails: How to execute function using a button without reload pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Well Maybe somebody asked this before, but i can't find the correct answer to my question…
I have a table with data charged using each/do, each item in the table has a button that adds that item to another table that should be seen in the same page, but above this first table.
When i click on the button, it executes the action, but the problem is that reloads the page.
What can i do to execute this action without reloading page and making this changes in real time???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use Ajax for this. Since you did not provide any code, I will give you pseudo-code to describe the idea.

Create an action in the controller that describes your behaviour. This action must respond to JS.

```
def do_something
  do_stuff
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { #handle HTML, i.e. full page reload }
    format.js # handle ajax request
  end
end
```

Then you will need to create a js template to render the result of you action. You will render JavaScript. So create a template called `do_something.js.erb`. This template will have the JavaScript code to implement the behaviour you described as well as any Ruby code.

Don't forget to create a route for your action. Also, depending on how you want to implement the method, you need to pass in a remote option to either your form, or your link. In case you are using a link you need to pass in the `method` option as well.

For exmaple:

```
= form_for @object, remote: true
```

Or

```
= link_to "Do Something", do_something_path, remote: true, method: :patch # or post, or put
```

Comment: Thank u so much @Mohamad it was very useful to check about javascripts… if you can please check this other post with the code.. That's what i'm trying to do.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065502/rails-fill-table-with-resulting-data-from-a-search-box 
Thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using **ajax**. You could write js code yourself, all by using the `remote: true` option for the button. If you using `remote: true` option, rails would send an ajax request instead, and your response should be js.

Example:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js # this one handle the request comes from `remote: true` button
end
```