# Rails: Fill Table with resulting data from a search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

As the question says, i'm trying to fill data in a table with the result from a search box in rails 4. I google it but i can't find the answer or even a example about how to do this.

This is my view:

```
<% title @sale.client_name %>
<div class="hero-unit">
    <CENTER><H1><%= @sale.client_name %> </H1>
    <br>
    <p>
        Numero de Factura:<br>
        <%= @sale.check_number %>
    </p>
    <p>
        Nit del Cliente:<br>
        <%= @sale.nit%>
    </p>
    <p>
        Fecha de venta:<br>
        <%= @sale.created_at %>
    </p>
    <p>    
        Total Venta:<br>
        <%= @sale.price %>
   </p>
   <p>
       <h2><Center><%= link_to_function "Ver Detalle de Venta", "$('#hide').toggle()" %>          </Center></h2>
<div id="hide" style="display:none">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><Center>Nombre</Center></th>
                <th><Center>Codigo del SubProducto</Center></th>
                <th><Center>Marca</Center></th>
                <th><Center>Categoria</Center></th>
                <th><Center>Precio</Center></th>        
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @sale.subproducts.each do |subproduct| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.product.name %></CENTER></td>
                    <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.code %></CENTER></td>
                    <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.product.brand %></CENTER></td>
                    <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.product.category %></CENTER></td>
                    <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.product.sale_price %></CENTER></td>
                    <td><%= link_to 'Eliminar de venta', :controller => :subproducts,  action => 'eliminar_subproducto_venta', :id => subproduct.id, :sale_id => @sale.id %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</p>

<% if @sale.confirmed == false %>
    <p>
        <h2><Center><%= link_to_function "Agregar Producto a venta",   "$('#subproduct').toggle()" %></Center></h2>
    <div id="subproduct" style="display:none">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                      <th><Center>Nombre</Center></th>
                      <th><Center>Codigo del SubProducto</Center></th>
                      <th><Center>Marca</Center></th>
                  <th><Center>Categoria</Center></th>
                  <th><Center>Precio De Venta</Center></th>        
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @subproducts.each do |subproduct| %>
                <tr>
                    <%if subproduct.available == true || subproduct.available == "NULL"%>
                    <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.product.name %></CENTER></td>
                    <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.code %></CENTER></td>
                    <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.product.brand %></CENTER></td>
                    <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.product.category %></CENTER></td>
                    <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.product.sale_price %></CENTER></td>

  <td><%= link_to 'Agregar a Venta', :controller => :subproducts, :action =>    'agregar_subproducto_venta', :id => subproduct.id, :sale_id => @sale.id %></td>
                        <% end %>
                    </tr>
               <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</p>
<%if @sale.price !=0 %>
<%= link_to 'Confirmar Venta', :controller => :sales, :action => 'confirm_sale',  :identificator => @sale.id%><br>
<%end%>

<%= link_to 'Cancelar Venta', :controller => :sales, :action => 'cancel_sale', :deletor => @sale.id%><br>
<%end%><br> 
<%= button_to 'Volver', sales_path, :method => :get, :class => 'btn btn-default' %><br>

</CENTER>
</div>
```

I wish the second table could be refreshed when user clicks on a search button with certain parameters.

Anyone could help me please?? i've been trying to do this for almost 2 weeks and i have no results =(

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. The easiest is to create js-view `searach_table.js.erb` for your table which will return you rendered html table

your js-view:

```
$("#your_second_table_container").html(<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'search_results', locals: {subproducts: @subproducts}))%>)
```

and your search link:

```
<%= link_to 'Search', <ypur_rout_to_js_view_action>, remote: true %>
```

Comment: Do u have some example for this please?? i'll be in a lot of troubles if i can't finish this homework for tomorrow @Aray

Comment: Do you have any action for your search? As I have already said you should add new view to this action with .js.erb extension. There you should render your table from partial using jQuery. Then you should request this js view via ajax.get or simply put Rails link with remote: true option. Also you can use form_for with the same remote: true attribute and f.submit

Comment: I'll take a look and comment my results. Thank u so much